# How to add a option menu in my android app?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to add an option menu in my android app. but I don't know what wrong with me when I run the it forced closed and when I search my log there are many error which i don't understand. I am learning android so I have a poor experience.

Please view my code and show me what wrong with me ?

```
   import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Option1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
          break;
        case R.id.item2:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Option2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
          break;
        case R.id.item3:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Option3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true; 
          break;          
        case R.id.item4:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Option4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
          break;
        case R.id.item5:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Option5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
          break;
        case R.id.item6:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Option6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true; 
          break;
        default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this will help you  remove break;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Option1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        case R.id.item2:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Option2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        case R.id.item3:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Option3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;           
        case R.id.item4:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Option4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        case R.id.item5:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Option5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        case R.id.item6:
          Toast.makeText(this, "Option6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;           
        default:
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        } 
    } 
}
```